# Runc PGP Signature Issue

Tags: docker, archlinux, runc

During the installation of docker on Archlinux, I got the following error :

```
error: runc: signature from "Frederik Schwan <frederik.schwan@linux.com>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/runc-1.0.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
```

Can someone help me resolve this issue since it prevents me from installing docker?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To solve "invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)" error in Arch Linux, we need to update the archlinux-keyring package.

```
$ sudo pacman -S archlinux-keyring
```

The above command will update the new keys and disable the revoked keys in your Arch Linux system.

source https://ostechnix.com/fix-invalid-corrupted-package-pgp-signature-error-arch-linux/

Comment: not gonna lie, but don't know what allows me to proceed, but I did install `archlinux-keyring` in the lot, so let just say it has contributed

Answer (score 6):

Today it works for me:

```
pacman-key --init
pacman-key --populate archlinux
```